# Question on nullity and set relations

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

If T and S are two transformations, if nullT>0 and nullS>0 does this imply null(T+S)>0?

And what about if rankT=0 and rankS=0, does rank(T+S)=0?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that $T$ and $S$ are linear.

First question: let $T,S :\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ given by

$$T= \operatorname{diag}(1,0)$$

and

$$S = \operatorname{diag}(0,1).$$

Then $\operatorname{nul}(T)>0$ and $\operatorname{nul}(S) >0.$ But $T+S= \operatorname{diag}(1,1)=I_2$, hence $\operatorname{nul}(T+S)=0.$

Second question: if $T :V \to W$  is linear and $\operatorname{rank}(T)=0$, then $T$ is the zero-transformation. Does this answer the second question ?